# how do i move a object with direction of touch unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner at game developing. I am developing a game where I have a ball and I want to move it by touch. I want it to move just like a soccer game where the ball can move in the direction of the touch.

However, right now it can only seem to move in the forward direction! Here is my code:

```
 public float ThroughSpped;
 public float ArchSpped;
void OnMouseDown() {

         distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, Camera.main.transform.position);
         Dragging = true;

     }
     public void OnMouseUp()
     {
         //Instantiate(this) ;
         this.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = true;



     this.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity += this.transform.forward*ThroughSpped;
         this.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity += this.transform.up*ArchSpped;
         Dragging = false;

     }

 void DraggingBall()
 {
     if (Dragging) 
     {
         Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
         Vector3 raypoint = ray.GetPoint (distance);
         transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (this.transform.position, raypoint, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
         Destroy(BallPrefabClone, 1f);
     }
 }
```

Comment: does your ball only move forward..is it something like throwing pokeball ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use touch phase to get the start position of the touch and end position of the touch to calculate the vector/direction of the touch

Then add force to your ball using this new vector

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 startPos;
    public Vector2 direction;
    public bool directionChosen;
    void Update()
    {
        // Track a single touch as a direction control.
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // Handle finger movements based on touch phase.
            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                // Record initial touch position.
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    startPos = touch.position;
                    directionChosen = false;
                    break;

                // Determine direction by comparing the current touch position with the initial one.
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    direction = touch.position - startPos;
                    break;

                // Report that a direction has been chosen when the finger is lifted.
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    directionChosen = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (directionChosen)
        {
            // Something that uses the chosen direction...
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.